# Mongoose $slice and get orginal size array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm currently trying to get the total amount of items in my News object, and return a slice of the items as objects. 
I found out how to use the $slice operator in my query, but I don't know how to get the original size of the array of items.
The code I'm currently using in NodeJS:

```
if (req.query.limit) {
    limit = 5;
}
News.findOne({ connected: club._id }, {items: {$slice: limit}}).exec(function (err, news) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
        });
    } else if (!news || news.items.length === 0) {
        res.jsonp([]);
    } else {
        const returnObj = { items: [], totalNumber: 0 };
        const items = news.items.sort(function (a, b) {
            return b.date - a.date
        });
        res.jsonp({
            items: items,
            totalNumber: news.items.length
        });
    }
});
```

The Mongo model:

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
 validator = require('validator'),
 Schema = mongoose.Schema;

 var NewsSchema = new Schema({
 connected: {
  type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  required: 'Gelieve een club toe te wijzen.',
  ref: 'Club'
 },
 items: [{
  userFirstName: String,
  action: String,
  date: Date,
  targetName: String
 }],
 created: {
  type: Date,
  default: Date.now
 }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('News', NewsSchema);
```

How would I do this efficiently?

Thanks!

EDIT: final code which works:

```
News.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        connected: club._id
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        totalNumber: {
            $size: '$items'
        },
        items: {
            $slice: ['$items', limit]
        }
    }
}
]).exec(function (err, news) {
    console.log(news);
    if (!news || news[0].items.length === 0) {
        res.jsonp([]);
    } else {
        res.jsonp(news[0]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot have both information at once using `find` and `$slice`.

---

**The soluce you have** :

---

Use `aggregate` to return the `count` and only the `sliced` values.

Like :

```
[{
   $project: {
     count: {
        $size: "$params",
     },

     params: {
        $slice: ["$params", 5],
     },
   },
}]
```

To help you out making `aggregate`, you can use the awesome `mongodb-compass` software and its `aggregate` utility tool.

[image]

---

Use a `find` without `$slice`, get the number of item there, and then `slice` in javascript the array before returning it.

---

---

EDIT :

```
   [{
      $sort: {
        'items.date': -1,
      },
    }, {
      $project: {
        count: {
          $size: "$items",
        },

        params: {
          $slice: ["$items", 5],
        },
      },
    }]
```

Comment: Could you add an example of the first solution where I would use an aggregate? The second solution is what I used before but did not feel was optimal..

Comment: Grégory, could you advice how I would go about this when I'd have to sort the items first to have the newest at the top, and then slice them? I tried by adding a $sort stage to my aggregation but this does not seem to have the wished for effect.